How can I list all papers citing a given paper and hosted on a given website?
I tried Google Scholar but it seems unable to list all papers citing a given paper and hosted on a given website (e.g., https://aclanthology.org/ or https://arxiv.com). Did I misuse Google Scholar and if not, which search engine can list all papers citing a given paper and hosted on a given website?

In Google Scholar, I tried the "search within citing articles" option:

But it doesn't seem to work with search search operator:


Google Scholar does not index papers by websites. So, no there is no way to do strictly what you are asking. However, Google Scholar indexes articles by publication source (journal, conference, working paper repository, etc.). So, you would need to reframe your search accordingly.
In fact, the two websites you listed are very different. As far as I can tell, ACL Anthology is effectively a scholarly database (equivalent to JSTOR, EBSCO, or Google Scholar itself) that aggregates articles from many different sources. I don't think Google Scholar would ever duplicate what ACL Anthology is doing or even try to record or make available that an article is available on ACL Anthology and EBSCO and Scopus, etc. That doesn't make much sense to me.
However, arXiv is indeed a publication source in its own right: it is a preprint archive. Google Scholar certainly records this information. You just have to filter your searches by arXiv:

Go to Google Scholar.
Click on the three bars for options.
Choose Advanced search".
In the field "Return articles published in", enter "arXiv".
Enter your other search options accordingly.


